# 3d point closest to multiple lines in 3D space

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, geometry, linear-algebra, computational-geometry

I search for non iterative, closed form,  algorithm to find Least squares solution for point closest to the set of 3d lines. It is similar to 3d point triangulation (to minimize re-projections) but seems to be be simpler and faster?

Lines can be described in any form, 2 points, point and unit direction or similar.

Comment: You might be better off asking this at math.stackexchange.com - then if you need help coding it up, coming back here.

Comment: You can test every point with the full set of lines. Some improvement can be achieved if you have points and lines sorted, so many of them can be discarded quickly. For point-line 3D distance you can use for example [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html)

Comment: Did my answer work for you? I thought it worked out pretty well, and you never commented.

Comment: Sorry, this task is delayed for a long time. When ill be back to it, a will write the comments and results. Sorry for this pause.

Answer (score 9):

Let the *i* th line be given by point *a<sub>i</sub>* and unit direction vector *d<sub>i</sub>*. We need to find the single point that minimizes the sum of squared point to line distances. This is where the gradient is the zero vector:

[image: unsimplified gradient of sum of squared distances]

Expanding the gradient,

[image: rewritten gradient set to zero]

Algebra yields a canonical 3x3 linear system,

[image: 3x3 linear system]

where the k'th row (a 3-element row vector) of matrix M is

[image: matrix M]

with vector *e<sub>k</sub>* the respective unit basis vector, and

[image: vector b]

It's not hard to turn this into code. I borrowed (and fixed a small bug in) a Gaussian elimination function from Rosettacode to solve the system. Thanks to the author!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef double VEC[3];
typedef VEC MAT[3];

void solve(double *a, double *b, double *x, int n);  // linear solver

double dot(VEC a, VEC b) { return a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2]; }

void find_nearest_point(VEC p, VEC a[], VEC d[], int n) {
  MAT m = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
  VEC b = {0, 0, 0};
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    double d2 = dot(d[i], d[i]), da = dot(d[i], a[i]);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ++ii) {
      for (int jj = 0; jj < 3; ++jj) m[ii][jj] += d[i][ii] * d[i][jj];
      m[ii][ii] -= d2;
      b[ii] += d[i][ii] * da - a[i][ii] * d2;
    }
  }
  solve(&m[0][0], b, p, 3);
}

// Debug printing.
void pp(VEC v, char *l, char *r) {
  printf("%s%.3lf, %.3lf, %.3lf%s", l, v[0], v[1], v[2], r);
} 

void pv(VEC v) { pp(v, "(", ")"); } 

void pm(MAT m) { for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) pp(m[i], "\n[", "]"); } 

// A simple verifier.
double dist2(VEC p, VEC a, VEC d) {
  VEC pa = { a[0]-p[0], a[1]-p[1], a[2]-p[2] };
  double dpa = dot(d, pa);
  return dot(d, d) * dot(pa, pa) - dpa * dpa;
}

double sum_dist2(VEC p, VEC a[], VEC d[], int n) {
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) sum += dist2(p, a[i], d[i]);
  return sum;
}

// Check 26 nearby points and verify the provided one is nearest.
int is_nearest(VEC p, VEC a[], VEC d[], int n) {
  double min_d2 = 1e100;
  int ii = 2, jj = 2, kk = 2;
#define D 0.01
  for (int i = -1; i <= 1; ++i) 
    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; ++j)
      for (int k = -1; k <= 1; ++k) {
        VEC pp = { p[0] + D * i, p[1] + D * j, p[2] + D * k };
        double d2 = sum_dist2(pp, a, d, n);
        // Prefer provided point among equals.
        if (d2 < min_d2 || i == 0 && j == 0 && k == 0 && d2 == min_d2) {
          min_d2 = d2;
          ii = i; jj = j; kk = k;
        }
      }
  return ii == 0 && jj == 0 && kk == 0;
}

void normalize(VEC v) {
  double len = sqrt(dot(v, v));
  v[0] /= len;
  v[1] /= len;
  v[2] /= len;
}

int main(void) {
  VEC a[] = {{-14.2, 17, -1}, {1, 1, 1}, {2.3, 4.1, 9.8}, {1,2,3}};
  VEC d[] = {{1.3, 1.3, -10}, {12.1, -17.2, 1.1}, {19.2, 31.8, 3.5}, {4,5,6}};
  int n = 4;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) normalize(d[i]);
  VEC p;
  find_nearest_point(p, a, d, n);
  pv(p);
  printf("\n");
  if (!is_nearest(p, a, d, n)) printf("Woops. Not nearest.\n");
  return 0;
}

// A linear solver from rosettacode (with bug fix: added a missing fabs())
#define mat_elem(a, y, x, n) (a + ((y) * (n) + (x)))

void swap_row(double *a, double *b, int r1, int r2, int n)
{
  double tmp, *p1, *p2;
  int i;

  if (r1 == r2) return;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    p1 = mat_elem(a, r1, i, n);
    p2 = mat_elem(a, r2, i, n);
    tmp = *p1, *p1 = *p2, *p2 = tmp;
  }
  tmp = b[r1], b[r1] = b[r2], b[r2] = tmp;
}

void solve(double *a, double *b, double *x, int n)
{
#define A(y, x) (*mat_elem(a, y, x, n))
  int i, j, col, row, max_row, dia;
  double max, tmp;

  for (dia = 0; dia < n; dia++) {
    max_row = dia, max = fabs(A(dia, dia));
    for (row = dia + 1; row < n; row++)
      if ((tmp = fabs(A(row, dia))) > max) max_row = row, max = tmp; 
    swap_row(a, b, dia, max_row, n);
    for (row = dia + 1; row < n; row++) {
      tmp = A(row, dia) / A(dia, dia);
      for (col = dia+1; col < n; col++)
        A(row, col) -= tmp * A(dia, col);
      A(row, dia) = 0;
      b[row] -= tmp * b[dia];
    }
  }
  for (row = n - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
    tmp = b[row];
    for (j = n - 1; j > row; j--) tmp -= x[j] * A(row, j);
    x[row] = tmp / A(row, row);
  }
#undef A
}
```

This isn't extensively tested, but seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Let base point of line is `p` and unit direction vector is `d`. 
Then distance from point `v` to this line might be calculated [using cross product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html)

```
SquaredDist = ((v -  p) x d)^2
```

Using Maple packet symbolic calculation, we can get

```
d := <dx, dy, dz>;
v := <vx, vy, vz>;
p := <px, py, pz>;
w := v - p;
cp := CrossProduct(d, w);
nrm := BilinearForm(cp, cp, conjugate=false);  //squared dist
nr := expand(nrm);       

//now partial derivatives
nrx := diff(nr, vx);     
//results:
nrx := -2*dz^2*px-2*dy^2*px+2*dz^2*vx+2*dy^2*vx
       +2*dx*py*dy-2*dx*vy*dy+2*dz*dx*pz-2*dz*dx*vz
nry := -2*dx^2*py-2*dz^2*py-2*dy*vz*dz+2*dx^2*vy
       +2*dz^2*vy+2*dy*pz*dz+2*dx*dy*px-2*dx*dy*vx
nrz := -2*dy^2*pz+2*dy^2*vz-2*dy*dz*vy+2*dx^2*vz
       -2*dx^2*pz-2*dz*vx*dx+2*dy*dz*py+2*dz*px*dx
```

To minimize sum of squared distances, we have to make system of linear equations for zero partial derivatives like this:

```
  vx*2*(Sum(dz^2)+Sum(dy^2)) + vy * (-2*Sum(dx*dy)) + vz *(-2*Sum(dz*dx)) = 
     2*Sum(dz^2*px)-2*Sum(dy^2*px) -2*Sum(dx*py*dy)-2*Sum(dz*dx*pz)

where 
  Sum(dz^2) = Sum{over all i in line indexes} {dz[i] * dz[i]}
```

and solve it for unknowns vx, vy, vz

**Edit: Old erroneous answer for planes instead of lines**, left for reference

If we use general equation of line

```
 A * x + B * y + C * z + D = 0
```

then distance from point (x, y, z) to this line is

```
Dist = Abs(A * x + B * y + C * z + D) / Sqrt(A^2 + B^2 + C^2)
```

To simplify - just normalize all line equations dividing by `Norm`'s

```
Norm = Sqrt(A^2 + B^2 + C^2)
a = A / Norm
b = B / Norm
c = C / Norm
d = D / Norm
```

now equation is

```
 a * x + b * y + c * z  + d = 0
```

and distance

```
Dist = Abs(a * x + b * y + c * z + d)
```

and we can use squared distances like LS method (`ai, bi, ci, di` are coefficients for i-th line)

```
F = Sum(ai*x + bi*y + ci * z + d)^2 = 
Sum(ai^2*x^2 + bi^2*y^2 + ci^2*z^2 + d^2 +
2 * (ai*bi*x*y + ai*ci*x*z + bi*y*ci*z + ai*x*di + bi*y*di + ci*z*di))

  partial derivatives
dF/dx = 2*Sum(ai^2*x + ai*bi*y + ai*ci*z + ai*di) = 0
dF/dy = 2*Sum(bi^2*y + ai*bi*x + bi*ci*z + bi*di) = 0
dF/dz = 2*Sum(ci^2*z + ai*ci*x + bi*ci*y + ci*di) = 0
  so we have system of linear equation 
x * Sum(ai^2) + y * Sum(ai*bi) + z * Sum(ai*ci)= - Sum(ai*di)
y * Sum(bi^2) + x * Sum(ai*bi) + z * Sum(bi*ci)= - Sum(bi*di)
z * Sum(ci^2) + x * Sum(ai*ci) + y * Sum(bi*ci)= - Sum(ci*di)

x * Saa + y * Sab + z * Sac = - Sad
x * Sab + y * Sbb + z * Sbc = - Sbd
x * Sac + y * Sbc + z * Scc = - Scd

where S** are corresponding sums
```

and can solve it for unknowns `x, y, z`

Comment: `A * x + B * y + C * z + D = 0` isn't a line in 3D, it's a plane. So probably the following computations don't match the OP's question as well.

Comment: Thought about it a little bit: the squared distance to a line can be computed by adding the squared distances to two orthogonal planes (that intersect in the line). So your approach can be useful if you create two planes for every line.

Comment: @Ralf Kleberhoff  OMG, yes :(   I made answer for 2D case, then dumbly expanded it to 3D case

Comment: I'm not seeing how your final solution works. There may be any number of points, so what you've written is any number of equations. But there are only 3 unknowns. As I said in comments (adjusting to your variable names), you'd need to solve `gradient( sum_i (d_i x (p_i - v))^2 ) = 0`, which is 3 equations in 3 unknowns.

Comment: @Gene I considered calculation of coordinates of point that minimizes sum of squared distances to given line set. It is exactly solving 3 equations in 3 unknowns (I wrote explicitly only one). Are you talking about choosing the best point from point set?

Comment: @MBo Okay. Sorry I misunderstood your notation.  See it now.  Did we get the same answer? Looks like it, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this for a sketch in Processing, so I ported Gene's answer. Works great and thought it might save someone else a little time. Unfortunately PVector/PMatrix don't have array accessors for vectors or matrices so I had to add these as local functions.

```
float getv(PVector v, int i) {
  if(i == 0) return v.x;
  if(i == 1) return v.y;
  return v.z;
}

void setv(PVector v, int i, float value) {
  if      (i == 0) v.x = value;
  else if (i == 1) v.y = value;
  else             v.z = value;
}

void incv(PVector v, int i, float value) {
  setv(v,i,getv(v,i) + value);
}

float getm(float[] mm, int r, int c)              { return mm[c + r*4]; }
void  setm(float[] mm, int r, int c, float value) { mm[c + r*4] = value; }
void  incm(float[] mm, int r, int c, float value) { mm[c + r*4] += value; }

PVector findNearestPoint(PVector a[], PVector d[]) {
  var mm = new float[16];
  var b  = new PVector();
  var n  = a.length;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    var d2 = d[i].dot(d[i]);
    var da = d[i].dot(a[i]);
    
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ++ii) {
      for (int jj = 0; jj < 3; ++jj) {
        incm(mm,ii,jj, getv(d[i],ii) * getv(d[i],jj));
      }
      
      incm(mm, ii,ii, -d2);
      incv(b, ii, getv(d[i], ii) * da - getv(a[i], ii) * d2);
    }
  }
  
  var p = solve(mm, new float[] {b.x, b.y, b.z});
  return new PVector(p[0],p[1],p[2]);
}


// Verifier
float dist2(PVector p, PVector a, PVector d) {
  PVector pa  = new PVector( a.x-p.x, a.y-p.y, a.z-p.z );
  float   dpa = d.dot(pa);
  return  d.dot(d) * pa.dot(pa) - dpa * dpa;
}

//double sum_dist2(VEC p, VEC a[], VEC d[], int n) {
float sum_dist2(PVector p, PVector a[], PVector d[]) {
  int n = a.length;
  float sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { 
    sum += dist2(p, a[i], d[i]);
  }
  return sum;
}

// Check 26 nearby points and verify the provided one is nearest.
boolean isNearest(PVector p, PVector a[], PVector d[]) {
  float min_d2 = 3.4028235E38;
  int   ii = 2, jj = 2, kk = 2;
  final float D  = 0.1f;
  
  for (int i = -1; i <= 1; ++i) 
    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; ++j)
      for (int k = -1; k <= 1; ++k) {
        PVector pp = new PVector( p.x + D * i, p.y + D * j, p.z + D * k );
        float d2 = sum_dist2(pp, a, d);
        // Prefer provided point among equals.
        if (d2 < min_d2 || i == 0 && j == 0 && k == 0 && d2 == min_d2) {
          min_d2 = d2;
          ii = i; jj = j; kk = k;
        }
      }
      
  return ii == 0 && jj == 0 && kk == 0;
}



void setup() {
  PVector a[] = {
    new PVector(-14.2, 17, -1), 
    new PVector(1, 1, 1),
    new PVector(2.3, 4.1, 9.8),
    new PVector(1,2,3)
  };
  
  PVector d[] = {
    new PVector(1.3, 1.3, -10),
    new PVector(12.1, -17.2, 1.1),
    new PVector(19.2, 31.8, 3.5),
    new PVector(4,5,6)
  };
  
  int n = 4;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    d[i].normalize();
    
  PVector p = findNearestPoint(a, d);
  println(p);
  
  if (!isNearest(p, a, d))
    println("Woops. Not nearest.\n");
}



// From rosettacode (with bug fix: added a missing fabs())
int mat_elem(int y, int x) { return y*4+x; }

void swap_row(float[] a, float[] b, int r1, int r2, int n)
{
  float tmp;
  int p1, p2;
  int i;

  if (r1 == r2) return;
  
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    p1 = mat_elem(r1, i);
    p2 = mat_elem(r2, i);
    
    tmp = a[p1];
    a[p1] = a[p2];
    a[p2] = tmp;
  }
  
  tmp = b[r1];
  b[r1] = b[r2];
  b[r2] = tmp;
}

float[] solve(float[] a, float[] b)
{
  float[] x = new float[] {0,0,0};
  int n = x.length;
  int i, j, col, row, max_row, dia;
  float max, tmp;

  for (dia = 0; dia < n; dia++) {
    max_row = dia;
    max = abs(getm(a, dia, dia));
    for (row = dia + 1; row < n; row++) {
      if ((tmp = abs(getm(a, row, dia))) > max) { 
        max_row = row;
        max = tmp;
      }
    }
    swap_row(a, b, dia, max_row, n);
    for (row = dia + 1; row < n; row++) {
      tmp = getm(a, row, dia) / getm(a, dia, dia);
      for (col = dia+1; col < n; col++) {
        incm(a, row, col, -tmp * getm(a, dia, col));
      }
      setm(a,row,dia, 0);
      b[row] -= tmp * b[dia];
    }
  }
  for (row = n - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
    tmp = b[row];
    for (j = n - 1; j > row; j--) {
      tmp -= x[j] * getm(a, row, j);
    }
    x[row] = tmp / getm(a, row, row);
  }
  
  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this in python/numpy. Took a bit to figure out which numpy functions matched with all those loops, but this matches Gene's answer.  I stepped through the code to ensure the intermediate values matched.

```py
import numpy as np

def findNearestPoint(pts, vecs):
    da = (vecs * pts).sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    b = (vecs * da - pts).sum(axis=0)
    c, d = pts.shape
    m = np.inner(vecs.T, vecs.T) - np.diag(np.full(d, c))
    return np.linalg.solve(m, b)

pts = np.array([[-14.2, 17, -1], [1, 1, 1], [2.3, 4.1, 9.8], [1,2,3]])
vecs = np.array([[1.3, 1.3, -10], [12.1, -17.2, 1.1], [19.2, 31.8, 3.5], [4,5,6]])
vecs = vecs / np.sqrt((vecs ** 2).sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True))

print(findNearestPoint(pts, vecs))
```